# Error building jpy `gcc: error: : No such file or directory`

Tags: java, python, linux, gcc

I am trying to build jpy for using the SNAP API of the european space agency in my ubuntu 16.04 with anaconda. After setting all my java, jdk and jvm paths correctly, I executed
`python setup.py build`
and got the following error:

```
src/main/c/jni/org_jpy_PyLib.c:254:26: warning: unused variable ‘state’ [-Wunused-variable]
         PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();
                          ^~~~~ gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/delgado/local/anaconda3/compiler_compat
-L/home/delgado/local/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/delgado/local/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_module.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_diag.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_conv.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_compat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_jtype.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_jarray.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_jobj.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_jmethod.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jpy_jfield.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/main/c/jni/org_jpy_PyLib.o -L
-L/home/delgado/local/anaconda3/lib -ljvm -ldl -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/jpy.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-Xlinker -rpath  gcc: error: : No such file or directory error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I do not know precisely which file is missing and why it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Using a built version of `jpy` in conda solved the issue. I suggest eg: `conda install -c terradue jpy`

hope this still helps somebody